# Extract data from CardScan Database using C#

Tags: c#, .net, database

I need to extract data from .CDB (CardScan Database) using C#. How i can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any documentation from [Dymo](http://www.cardscan.com/index.asp)? Have you contacted CardScan Support?

Edit: a quick search revealed the following:

> CardScan doesn't use ODBC, DBF, or
>   such database formats. CardScan uses
>   its own proprietary database format,
>   which cannot be accessed by any other
>   program.

Source: [Dymo Customer Support](https://dymo.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1099/~/cardscan-and-odbc-files)

Answer (score 0):

As this thread pops up on top Position on Google while searching, I think an update is ok:

Dymo has an SDK on their Homepage.
This SDK Shows printing and scanning with CardScan.
Included are source code samples to access scanners and the cardscan database.
The samples are in several programming languages including VB.NET